# concat one thousand dataframes(30mb each) takes half an hour using rechunk

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dataset partitioned by date which consist of one thousand of arrow files with 300 columns. I tried to read it with pl.read_ipc and concat it with rechunk=True. The rechunk step took more than half an hour on my server with 1TB RAM. Is there a way to accelerate this procedure or any suggestions for processing or storage in this scenario? Many thanks for any help and effort in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have to read all cells in the files just to concatenate them. I don't know about the arrow format, but if they are binary or text files, you can just concatenate their lines without reading them.

Assuming you have a list of filenames ready:

```
outfile = open("concatenated.txt","w")

for filename in list_of_names:
    with open(filename,"r") as infile:
        for line in infile.readlines():
            outfile.write(line)

outfile.close()
```

Notes:

- if the files are binary, just use "wb" and "rb" as file modes, respectively
- if the files contain headers, just skip them by using `readlines()[1:]`